# Isotope img scr and links broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I've gotten the isotope plugin to work my problem in chrome and all other browsers, it appears as it there isn't any photo. For example, you can't right click to say "save image as". Not even images with links work.

Here's my code although it's not working in jsfiddle and I have not clue why since it works on my localhost.
[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkyDrew/7b75m/3/embedded/result/)

Any help appreciated.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $container = $('#container');

        $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
            $container.isotope({
                photoSelector : '.photo',
                       masonry: {
                           columnWidth: 60
                       },
                // options...
            });
        });
    });
</script>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know too much about how jsFiddle is supposed to work, but it looks as though the images aren't being loaded because they don't exist. Try putting in absolute image URLs because at the moment it's looking for the images in http://fiddle.jshell.net/SkyDrew/7b75m/3/show/light/images/test/ and getting 404 errors.